# Boost interprocess lib lib performance issue with named mutex

Tags: c++, performance, boost, interprocess

Is there a konwn issue with boost interprocess lib with named mutex, boost version 1.36.

Basically we do:

```
#define BT_MY_LOCK "XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX"
#define WAIT_LOCK named_mutex myLock(open_or_create, BT_TICKET_LIB_LOCK);   \
boost::posix_time::ptime expire_time = microsec_clock::universal_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(2);    \
scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(ticketLock, expire_time); \
if (!lock.owns()) throw mutex_failure();
```

Then we use this macro whenever we need.

But this seems to have caused the a lot uncessary C:\ folder open & close activity whenever boost try to create the XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX file under temp folder under C:\ drive. It seems like for each useufl XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX file acess, there are about 25ish C:\ Open , Close.

So it looks like from promon:

```
XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX access 1 
XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX access 2
C:\ open
C:\ close
C:\ open
C:\ close
...
repeat 25 times 
...
XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX access 1 
XX_BT_MY_LOCK_XX access 2
C:\ open
C:\ close
C:\ open
C:\ close
...
repeat 25 times
```

I am just wondering is the a known boost issue ?

Comment: 1.36? You do know what 1.51 is out?

Comment: @Nim, yea but this some old code maintannce so please don't comment on the old boost version.